# Android, setVisibility/animation issue

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a `linearLayout` that disappears when I hit a button, it comes back when I press the button again. But it does it so fast, it doesn't look nice.
I do this via:

```
disappearView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I would like to add some animation... If I just set visibity to invisible the space where the layout was is still there. So I tried this:

```
if (disappearView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
            disappearView.startAnimation(out);
            disappearView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            disappearView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else {
            Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
            disappearView.startAnimation(in);
            disappearView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
        }
```

This does the animation too fast and disappears. You can't see it at all. Do I need to use a thread to start `gone` after `invisible` is set...or a delay? Or is there a better way of doing all this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish...do you want the LinearLayout to fade out over a little bit of time rather than instantly disappear? And then once it fades out be removed from the parent via View.GONE?

If so, you can use an AlphaAnimation for the fade out and then attach a listener like EvZ posted:

```
AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // start alpha, end alpha
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(1000); // time for animation in milliseconds
fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true); // make the transformation persist
fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
});

linearLayout.setAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want. At the moment I don't alpha fadeout, I use that built in one AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation...it just slides the layout slowly off one side of the screen. The it brings it back in a different manner, more like alpha changing. Will try that listener thanks :) I had seen that alpha animation with listener but wondered if the animation I was using would do similar.

Comment: I need to call setVisibility(View.Visible or View.Gone) accordingly before this and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Ben I am doing same but first view becomes visible and then animation starts with a very little delay and hence animation doesn't look smooth. I don't want delay between view's visibility and start of animation. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @DhruvamGupta, I think it would help if you ask a new question and submit a gif of the behavior you're seeing. Are you trying to get rid of the "very little delay" at the start, or do you need to change how the view looks when it first becomes visible before the animation?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `onAnimationEnd` : [Animation.AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29)